# How to set inference rules next to each other in semantic?

Tags: line-breaking

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{semantic}
\begin{document}
  \setpremisesend{0pt}\setnamespace{0pt}%
  \inference{A_1\\A_2&A_3}{C_1}
  \quad
  \inference{A_4\\A_5&A_6}{C_2}%
\end{document}
```

to latex or pdflatex yields two inference rules which are not on the same vertical level (base line?), but the second one is below right the first one:

[image: output]

Probably, an `\inference{…}{…}` simply inserts a line break at the end. Why? How to set the two inference rules on the same vertical level, i.e., the second rule to the right on the first one? Or how to prevent the terminating line breaks by default?

Comment: The documentation shows some side-by-side examples with elements separated by a double backslash.  I didn't dig into the code or try to test.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It didn't occur to me that I could look into the source. Now I see there how they do it: `\[\inference[…]{…}{…}\;\;\;\;\inference[…]{…}{…}\]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{semantic}

\setpremisesend{0pt}
\setnamespace{0pt}

\begin{document}

\mbox{\inference{A_1\\A_2&A_3}{C_1}}%
\quad
\mbox{\inference{A_4\\A_5&A_6}{C_2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or typeset them in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{semantic}

\setpremisesend{0pt}
\setnamespace{0pt}

\begin{document}

\[
\inference{A_1\\A_2&A_3}{C_1}
\quad
\inference{A_4\\A_5&A_6}{C_2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Following @barbarabeeton, I looked into semantic.dtx, and there the authors write `\[\inference[…]{…}{…}\;\;\;\;\inference[…]{…}{…}\]`.  On the other hand, they also say, “So even if the declaration above has been given, `\inference` is never be executed in math mode.” Any preference on `\mbox`es in text mode vs. `\[…\]` for the issue at hand or is it really up to me?